# Why is my requests.Session() starting a new HTTP connection when used within a multiprocessing.Process?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multiprocessing, keep-alive

Take this Python 2.7 script as an example, it uses the multiprocessing module:

```py
# Local test
import urllib2
import shlex
import requests
import json
import threading
import os
import logging
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from threading import current_thread

sessions = {}
logging.basicConfig(filename='/tmp/python.log',level=logging.DEBUG)


def worker(session,queue):
    logging.exception('parent process: ' + str(os.getppid()) + ', process id: ' + str(os.getpid()) + ' -- ' + str(session.verify))
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8487/test'
    response = session.get(url, verify=True, timeout=5).json()
    queue.put(response)
    return response

def doWork():
    global sessions
    try:
        thread = threading.current_thread()
        if not id(thread) in sessions:
            sessions[id(thread)] = requests.Session()
            session = sessions[id(thread)]
            session.verify = 'new session - ' + current_thread().name
        else:
            session = sessions[id(thread)]
            session.verify = 'reuse session - ' + current_thread().name
        queue = Queue()
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(session,queue))
        p.start()
        p.join()
        return queue.get()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
        return "error"
```

Please don't worry about the "session registry". This is necessary for a greater context, but should not have any effect on what I'm doing. The thing that I want to show is that I am actually reusing the same session object in the forked process. So I am running this script like this:

```
python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 00:51:29)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> test.doWork()
{u'name': 3}
>>> test.doWork()
{u'name': 3}
>>> test.doWork()
{u'name': 3}
>>>
```

And my python.log shows this:

```
ERROR:root:parent process: 10092, process id: 10240 -- new session - MainThread
None
INFO:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 10
ERROR:root:parent process: 10092, process id: 10253 -- reuse session - MainThread
None
INFO:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 10
ERROR:root:parent process: 10092, process id: 10261 -- reuse session - MainThread
None
INFO:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 127.0.0.1
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 10
```

Why is the session starting a new HTTP connection, although it's the same session object? If I change the code to call `worker` directly, without multiprocessing, it works as expected, and the connection is reused.

Just for reference, I am using a mock HTTP server (mock-server.com) that reports the following:

```
2020-09-25 08:34:55 5.11.1 INFO 1080 returning response:

  {
    "body" : "{\"name\":3}",
    "delay" : {
      "timeUnit" : "MILLISECONDS",
      "value" : 30
    },
    "connectionOptions" : {
      "closeSocket" : false
    }
  }

 for request:

  {
    "method" : "GET",
    "path" : "/test",
    "headers" : {
      "Host" : [ "127.0.0.1:8487" ],
      "Connection" : [ "keep-alive" ],
      "Accept-Encoding" : [ "gzip, deflate" ],
      "Accept" : [ "*/*" ],
      "User-Agent" : [ "python-requests/2.6.0 CPython/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64" ],
      "content-length" : [ "0" ]
    },
    "keepAlive" : true,
    "secure" : false
  }

 for action:

  {
    "body" : "{\"name\":3}",
    "delay" : {
      "timeUnit" : "MILLISECONDS",
      "value" : 30
    },
    "connectionOptions" : {
      "closeSocket" : false
    }
  }
```

And the server is replying with keep-alive:

```
curl -v 127.0.0.1:8487/test
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 8487 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8487 (#0)
> GET /test HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8487
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< connection: keep-alive
< content-length: 10
<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
{"name":3}
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the http server. Does the return header have `Connection: Keep-Alive`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive

Comment: Yes, it is. It is working fine without multiprocessing. I have updated the question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

request.Session() has a built-in thread pool with 10 threads (via HTTPAdapter), you may be hitting that internal pool initialization. First, in your usage you may not need a wrapper pool as session already has a built-in pool. Or, restrict the internal pool to 1 thread to see if that helps

```
session = requests.session()
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=1)
session.mount("http://", adapter)
```